# Problem mixing titletoc and chapterbib with sectionbib option

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, cross-referencing, titletoc, chapterbib

Consider the following files:

```
.
├── main.tex
├── preface.tex
├── preface.bib
├── chapter.tex
└── chapter.bib
```

The contents of these files are detailed at the end of this post.

---

The important part is the following. I am using `\usepackage{titletoc}` in conjunction with `\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}`. When `titletoc` is not used in a chapter (see `preface.tex`), then everything goes fine and the bibliography is added at the end of the chapter. However when `titletoc` is used in a chapter (see `chapter.tex`) in the following way:

```
\chapter{Chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{}{}
% ... CONTENTS HERE ...
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{chapter}
```

then one of the two package seems to fail, and I end up with the bibliography being a chapter (and not a section within a chapter as I would like), and the citations failing and appearing as `[?]`.

**Question: how to make it work properly and have chapters starting with a local table of contents, and ending with a section containing the references?**

*Download of the files:* [link](https://easyupload.io/y5us32) (this is not necessary, it's just for those who want to avoid to have to copy/paste)

---

[image: illustration]

---

**`main.tex:`**

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[oneside, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}  
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\include{preface}
\mainmatter
\include{chapter}
\end{document}
```

**`preface.tex:`**

```
% preface.tex
\chapter{Preface}

\section{Preface first section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{preface:ref1}

\section{Preface second section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{preface:ref2}

\section{Preface third section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{preface:ref3}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{preface}
```

**`preface.bib:`**

```
% preface.bib
@article{preface:ref1,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {Preface1},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}

@article{preface:ref2,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {Preface2},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}

@article{preface:ref3,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {Preface3},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}
```

**`chapter.tex:`**

```
% chapter.tex
\chapter{First chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{}{}

\section{First chapter first section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{chapter:ref1}

\section{First chapter second section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{chapter:ref2}

\section{First chapter third section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{chapter:ref3}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{chapter}
```

**`chapter.bib:`**

```
% chapter.bib
@article{chapter:ref1,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {FirstChapter1},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}

@article{chapter:ref2,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {FirstChapter2},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}

@article{chapter:ref3,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {FirstChapter3},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}
```

Comment: I would look at etoc and biblatex instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a conflict with the packages. (The sectionbib option and the use of hyperref are unrelated.) When generating a TOC (or LOF/LOT) chapterbib inserts settings for the included-file (chapter) indicator, so any cites in the title or caption will be produced properly in the TOC/LOF/LOT (even though such cites are bad). No attempt to preserve local context is made, with the assumption that the TOC is in the main file, but that leaves the indicator pointing to the main file at the end of the TOC.

I see that the partial TOC is performed in a group, so the quickest fix is to change `\gdef` to `\def` in the definition

```
\def\@CB@wtoc#1{\string\@writefile{#1}{\gdef % <- change to \def
  \string\the@ipfilectr{\@extra@b@citeb}}}%
```

(Change it yourself on line 24 of chapterbib.sty!) I expect I may introduce some more complicated state restoration, along the lines of

```
 \def\@tempa#1{\AtBeginDocument{\if@filesw
     \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile
       {#1}{\string\global\string\let\string\save@ipfilectr\string\the@ipfilectr}}\fi}}
 \@tempa{toc}\@tempa{lof}\@tempa{lot}
 \def\@tempa#1{\AtEndDocument{\if@filesw
     \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile
       {#1}{\string\global\string\let\string\the@ipfilectr\string\save@ipfilectr}}\fi}}
 \@tempa{toc}\@tempa{lof}\@tempa{lot}
```

By the way, it seems like a lot of trouble to have separate bib files for each chapter. I wouldn't do that unless the chapters were written by different authors independently.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the state restoration and where to put it?

Comment: That block could go anywhere in chapterbib.sty, or after `\makeatletter` in the document preamble. It uses `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument` to make the `.toc` (and `.ptc`) files start with `\global\let\save@ipfilectr\the@ipfilectr` to remember the pointer; and end with `\global\let\the@ipfilectr\save@ipfilectr` to restore the original setting.